# Best way to combine the output of 2 neural networks?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, ensemble-learning

I have 2 neural network models (pre-trained transformers BERT, but the input data (fine-tuning data) is different in each model) it's a binary classification task (1 or 0).

**Model 1** --> achieves an overall 45% F-measure (which is not that good of course)

**Model 2**---> achieves overall 80% F-measure (which is better).

However, most of the sentences which are wrongly classified in **model 2** (the 80% one) are correctly classified in **model 1** (although it achieves a low F-measure but it gets what model2 doesn't get).

What is the best way to combine the output of model1 and model2 ?
The output can either be 0 or 1, or we could look at the probability of each score [3.2,0.5] the former is the probability of 0 the latter is prob. of 1 (i.e: soft-max layer output).

What I did is soft-voting with the probability of each model output for each label as seen in the code below, but it only improved 1% so the F-measure is 81% instead of 80%, that why I want to check if there's a better way to go?

```
soft_voting=[]
import collections
for model1, model2 in zip(model_outputs,model_outputs2):
    
    prob_zero=max(model1[0],model2[0])
    prob_one=max(model1[1],model2[1])
    soft_voting_result=0 if prob_zero>prob_one else 1
    soft_voting.append(soft_voting_result)
```

I also tried replacing max with average or weighted average but didn't notice much of a difference.

Comment: One thing you have to remember is that 80% of accuracy can be an average performance if data is imbalanced (let say 80/20). In that case, stacking the 2 models is not relevant in my opinion.

Comment: @DimitriK.Sifoua, data is balanced, however, I shuffle the training and test set, so the 80% actually fluctuates between 79~83 and the 45% fluctuates between 40~46.

Comment: If data is balanced, you have to keep the same proportion (stratification) in train and test sets. After saying that, 45% of F1 score with well balanced data is a bad performance. So I'd suggest you to keep trying to improve the model 1 before trying to ensemble the two models.

Comment: @DimitriK.Sifoua, that is a good point, scitkitlearn train_test split function supports stratification, I will add it to the function call. The thing is the 45% model is actually from training on a similar task (but not the same task) that is why it predicts unseen sentences better than model2, however its overall performance is not that good. When I do a 2-stage training by training my model on model2 dataset (original train) then model1 dataset (similar task), model1 improves to almost 55%, but still voting gets 1% improvement on the performance of model2, so not much improvement! any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The best results I have achieved is to actually use 3 models. I take as the final prediction the case where A: all of the models predict the same class or if that is not the case B: select the class where 2 of the 3 models agree. Since you are doing binary classification one of these will always be the case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gerry. The problem is model1 uses a dataset from a different task, that's why it achieves low around 45% but it gets the answer correct for what model 2 doesn't. I tried what you proposed with model3, where model3 is trained on same dataset of the original task, so its performance is like model2 around 80% yet it also fails where model 2 fails, so I am not gaining anything from majority voting, because model2 and model3 almost always agree.

Comment: have you tried merging the two datasets?

Comment: Yes, performance fluctuates 79~82%, so mainly like model2 performance, although the dataset from model1 is twice the size of model2